# Is 'Critique of Pure Reason' a contradictory project?

Tags: kant, critique-of-pure-reason

Kant is *using* Pure Reason to *critique* Pure Reason. [Is that not contradictory?](https://youtu.be/JE-pY-1J_WA?t=111)

**PS:** I have not read the book yet.

Comment: how do you expect an answer if you haven't read the book? How are you supposed to judge the answers? Read it and then come back, you can find it online

Comment: Why exactly would it be a contradictory project? Is it contradictory for a linguist to use language to speak about the language? I see the intuition behind your question and I know that I am nitpicking, but I think this is also an almost compulsory first step toward an answer.

Comment: Maybe... as any other philosophical endeavor using reason to inquiry about the foundation of rationality.

Comment: Offering a critique of something doesn't mean that you are saying something is worthless or unusable. Why would this be a contradiction?

Comment: I believe you want to say [self-referential](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/self-reference/), not contradictory.